# Get a local text file in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I was following a tutorial online on using tensorflow and he used this code:

```
prepWork = tf.keras.utils.get_file('shakespeare.txt', urlToTextFile)
```

If I want to use this code for my own project, I need to read a local text file, let's say 'prepWork.txt', from my machine. I can't use get_file, because that only works for online files. How would I do this? Everything I've tried before doesn't work.

Comment: there are other methods to read text file in python and tensorflow. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/read_file

Answer (score 0):

You can find a TextLoader class which reads a text file and transforms it into batches of consecutive fixed sized length of words in the following repository (in utils.py file) https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow/blob/master/utils.py